# docker version fails on OS X

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a fresh, first-time install of boot2docker on OS X 10.10.4 and I am getting the following error:

```
$ boot2docker version
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
Git commit: 8fdc6f5

$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
An error occurred trying to connect: Get https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/version: dial tcp 192.168.59.103:2376: i/o timeout
```

Everything I read says this problem was fixed in 1.7.1 of boot2docker... what am I missing?

**Update 1**
Upon a suggestion below I tried a few things. Here's the output:

```
$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
$ openssl s_client -connect 192.168.59.103:2376
^C  <--- I gave up after a while... nothing was responding.
$ boot2docker ssh
                        ##         .
                  ## ## ##        ==
               ## ## ## ## ##    ===
           /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
      ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
           \______ o           __/
             \    \         __/
              \____\_______/
 _                 _   ____     _            _
| |__   ___   ___ | |_|___ \ __| | ___   ___| | _____ _ __
| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| __| __) / _` |/ _ \ / __| |/ / _ \ '__|
| |_) | (_) | (_) | |_ / __/ (_| | (_) | (__|   <  __/ |
|_.__/ \___/ \___/ \__|_____\__,_|\___/ \___|_|\_\___|_|
Boot2Docker version 1.7.1, build master : c202798 - Wed Jul 15 00:16:02 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.7.1, build 786b29d
docker@boot2docker:~$ ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:7B:39:40
          inet addr:192.168.59.103  Bcast:192.168.59.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe7b:3940/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3130 (3.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2442 (2.3 KiB)
```

**Update 2**
Should have rebooted... not used to caring about that when not in Windows but it seems something on my Mac had gotten out of whack... now it works.

Comment: the openssl output shows that the docker daemon is not listening on  192.168.59.103:2376. You tried eval $(boot2docker shellinit); docker version?

Comment: Thanks for the help @christian but I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Please try `eval $(boot2docker shellinit)` and issue `docker version` again.

If that doesn´t help, please try `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.59.103:2376` to see there is something listening on `192.168.59.103:2376`

If there is nothing listening, then your `docker version` tries to connect to the wrong address and you have to set your Variable `DOCKER_HOST` to the right address.

You could also check with `boot2docker ssh` if boot2docker is up and with  `boot2docker ip` to which ip boot2docker is bound (should be 192.168.59.103).

Comment: I have updated the original post with the output from your suggestions... no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I should have done troubleshooting step 1: reboot. For whatever reason, that fixed it.